# Configure ASP.NET MVC 4 web app to use Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, identityserver4, wif, ws-federation, thinktecture-ident-server

I don't have much understating how make existing old **ASP.NET MVC 4** app(claim-based auth, windows identity foundation, ws-federation, old thinktecture identity server) to use new **Identity Server 4 with WS-Federation plugin**.
Does it require to substitute WIF's Authentication and Session modules with OWIN middleware as stated [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.WsFederation) or use both?

Here's configs from web.config:

```
        <httpModules>
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpModules>
...
<microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://localhost/" />
      </audienceUris>
      <federatedAuthentication>
        <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://localhost/LoginEndpoint/issue/wsfed" realm="https://localhost/" requireHttps="false" />
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" hideFromScript="true" />
      </federatedAuthentication>
      <applicationService>
        <claimTypeRequired>
          <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" optional="true" />
          <claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" optional="true" />
        </claimTypeRequired>
      </applicationService>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="XXXXXXXXXXXX" name="https://localhost/LoginEndpoint/" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <serviceCertificate>
        <!--Needed for cookie encyption in web-farm environment. -->
        <certificateReference x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
      </serviceCertificate>
    </service>
  </microsoft.identityModel>
```

Any help will be appreciated! Even suggestions if there are better frameworks or approaches for modern SSO solutions that can be used with old ASP.NET MVC 4 clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client side, you can use the [OWIN stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Note this is .NET Core but the principles are the same.

You can still use WIF if you want to. You just need to change the IDP URL and wtrealm parameters.

On the server side you need the Rock Solid Knowledge WS-Fed plugin.

Follow this [approach](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-the-rock-solid-knowledge-ws-federation-stack-on-identityserver4-to-adfs-4-0-6ef1b74bc17e).

The other way is to change to OpenID Connect that idsrv4 supports out of the box.

There's a good [walk-through](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html) here.

Comment: ADFS confuses me. In my case authentication has nothing to do with AD.

Comment: If I will go for Idsrv4 and owin middleware on client, what is the purpose of using WIF? And should I remove all previous authentitication-related code like SessionAuthenticationModule and WSFederationAuthenticationModule as owin will do their job, right?

Comment: Yes - you don't need to use ADFS. That was just an example that shows how to configure the idsrv4 parameters.

Comment: If you go the OWIN route, the WS-Fed is built in to that. So no need for WIF. Yes - you can remove those modules.

Comment: Just curious what are the benefits of using ws-federation protocol if existing WIF logic will be removed. Why don't use newer and more popular openId/aouth2 with same efforts to rework

Comment: Yup - both are much the same. Go with OpenID Connect if you want the newer stuff.